# API Management Policy - pass x-www-form-urlencoded body

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an old asmx web service that can be invoked using postman like so

[image: Postman]

I want to expose this via API Management as a JSON endpoint and then have a policy to transform XML but I'm unsure how to set the request details in the policy

I have tried to do this below (and variations of it) but I always get the message error 'requestXML is missing'

```
<set-body template="liquid">
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <soap:Body>
                    requestXml: "<Request Caller="Harness"><GetEmployerOfferings><EmployerCode>CHCA</EmployerCode></GetEmployerOfferings></Request>"
                </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
        </set-body>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
        </set-header>
```

How do I pass this to the backend service via an APIM policy?

Comment: how does your JSON request body look like?

Comment: I'm just trying to hard code passing the requestXml to the backend for now but my json request would look something like this...{
  "getEmployerOfferings": {
    "requestXml": "sample"
  }
}

Comment: Do you mean the `"sample"` in the json your provided above refer to `<Request Caller="Harness"><GetEmployerOfferings><EmployerCode>CHCA</EmployerCode></GetEmployerOfferings></Request>` ? You want to request the apim with a request body in json, but the property `requestXml` of the json is still a xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, I'm a little confused about your json sample as I asked in comment. But I can also provide some information for your reference.

**1.** If you want to test hard code passing the requestXml to the backend, the correct format should be `requestXml=xxxx` but not `requestXml:xxxx` because you use "**x-www-form-urlencoded**" as **content-type** (in postman we can use `requestXml:xxxx`). So the policy in apim should be:

```
<set-body>requestXml=<Request Caller="Harness"><GetEmployerOfferings><EmployerCode>CHCA</EmployerCode></GetEmployerOfferings></Request></set-body>
```

But as your body contains xml `<>`, so it will remove `<Request Caller="Harness"><GetEmployerOfferings><EmployerCode>CHCA</EmployerCode></GetEmployerOfferings></Request>` automatically after save the policy. Only leave `<set-body>requestXml=</set-body>`, so test with hard code may not success.

**2.** And to my understanding, if you want to request the APIM with the json data like below:

```
{
    "getEmployerOfferings": {
        "requestXml": "<Request Caller=\"Harness\"><GetEmployerOfferings><EmployerCode>CHCA</EmployerCode></GetEmployerOfferings></Request>"
    }
}
```

If your request json like the sample above, you can refer to the policy below:

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-body>@{
        var request = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>();
        var xmlstring = request["getEmployerOfferings"]["requestXml"].ToString();
        var result = "requestXml=" + xmlstring;
        return result;
    }</set-body>
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
    </set-header>
</inbound>
```

Test the apim, we can find the final request body after  operation, it shows:
[image]

Comment: you are right.  The correct format needs to be requestXml=.  I also removed the soap:envelope tags and did a straight <set-body> like you said.  In addition I set it up as a Get method in APIM and changed it to Post within the policy to post to the backend